# Is there a JavaScript "setInterval()" equivalent in Go?

Tags: function, go, asynchronous

I'm new to Go and I want to call a function repeatedly and asynchronously after a specific time interval just like how the `setInterval()` function works in JavaScript. I want to build an API which returns some news headlines from different websites but scraping the websites on every request would be very slow. So, I want to call the web scraping function asynchronously in the background after every 10 minutes to update the headline data.

```
// I want to call this function every 10 minutes
func WebScraper(data map[string]interface{}) {  
    // Web scraping stuff
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: is there a easier way to do this? Like a single function which would take the web scraping function as argument and the time interval as argument and run it in the background?

Comment: `go func() { for range time.NewTicker(time.Minute * 10).C { doSomeThing() }}()`